# Why does 'top' fail to run via 'xargs'?

Tags: xargs, top

I am trying to run `top` with multiple PIDs using `-p` option and [`xargs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs). However, `top` fails to run with error `top: failed tty get`:

```
$ pgrep gvfs | paste -s -d ',' | xargs -t top -p
top -p 1598,1605,1623,1629,1635,1639,1645,1932,2744
top: failed tty get
```

I used the `-t` option for `xargs` to see the full command which is about to be executed. It seems fine and I can run it successfully by hand:

```
top -p 1598,1605,1623,1629,1635,1639,1645,1932,2744
```

However, it does not run with `xargs`. Why is that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Turns out that there is a special option `--open-tty` in `xargs` for interactive applications like `top`. From [man xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
   -o, --open-tty
          Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before
          executing the command.  This is useful if you want xargs
          to run an interactive application.
```

The command to run `top` should be:

```
pgrep gvfs | paste -s -d ',' | xargs --open-tty top -p
```

Comment: That's a useful feature to know about. When running curses-based applications, I always used command substitution (as in the other answer). While this option is not specified by POSIX, I see it is supported by GNU and BSD implementations of `xargs`.

Answer (score 21):

`top` is an interactive program, for instance you can type `i` to toggle showing idle processes. Whilst it could arrange to read from `/dev/tty` in practice it expects that stdin is connected to the terminal.

For your example just use command substitution rather than `xargs`, e.g.

```
top -p "$(pgrep gvfs | paste -s -d ',')"
```

The shell first runs the pgrep and paste, gets the output from those commands and then invokes top with that output.

Comment: This is *command* substitution, not *process* substitution. Process substitution is with `<( ... )`

Comment: @user000001 True, edited -thanks.